# Enum from value back to name for concatenation

Tags: c, enums

I have a problem, where I need to find the enum name back from its value.
So I have the following defined in a header file:

```
#define ADDR_TO_SETTING(ADDR) setting_ ## ADDR

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t setting_ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE;
} Settings_t;

typedef enum
{
    ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE
} Settings_addr_e
```

Now I have a function, with an address parameter, where I want to set a setting from the address:

```
Settings_t curr_settings;

void Settings_set_value_uint8_t(Settings_addr_e addr, uint8_t val)
{
    curr_settings.ADDR_TO_SETTING(addr) = val;
}
```

So how do I resolve the parameter addr back to ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE?

Comment: You can't get the name of the enum. It's not relevant. Or am I misunderstanding your question? Does your code even compile..?

Comment: It is relevant in this case, since the settings are named like the addresses, except that it starts with a "setting_"

Comment: Are you asking how to assign the enum variable a value?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: No, I'm asking on how to resolve addr as the argument (for example value 0) back to ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE, the name, since this is needed to resolve curr_settings.ADDR_TO_SETTING(addr) to curr_settings.setting_ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE

Comment: You don't. Struct member names only exist at compile time. You can't access variables by name at runtime.

Comment: Ok, so lets say I have a "const *char settings_t_names" array with the names, i still can not resolve it somehow. If I put curr_settings.ADDR_TO_SETTING(settings_t_names[0]) = val; inside, ADDR_TO_SETTING() resolves to setting_settings_t_names

Comment: I will correct myself. It's just not possible to do what you are asking. But I'm still confused as to why you "need" to do this. Because there might just be something you're not understanding. It sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: You seem to be confused about where macros come into play during the translation of C code.